# parsing coordinates from file with python and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I have a file with coordinates produced from a MD simulation package.

the format is as follows:

(1.323232, 1.22323, 3.23123)

You can also specify the output of the coordinates as follows, without commas:

(1.323232 1.22323 3.23123)

How do I parse such a line in an array with python. 
Specifically how do I remove the parentheses.
In C this is pretty easy to do with scanf?

Comment: How exactly would you parse a line with optional commas with scanf?

Comment: Are there multiple sets of coordinates per line, or just one set?

Comment: sscanf (line,"(%lf, %lf, %lf)",&vx[i],&vy[i],&vz[i]);

Comment: I meant sscanf not scanf sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Dimo: Have you tried that? If you give it a line without commas, it will return `1` and leave `vy[i]` and `vz[i]` unchanged.

Comment: The above case is for the comma separated version and it works fine, I have tested it.The problem when translating to python is to deal with the parentheses

Comment: @Dimo: So you want to write two different functions for the two different cases? I suppose in C there's no obvious way around that, but in Python, you don't have to.

Comment: the default export version of the package uses commas so I was trying to figure out how to discard parentheses and commas and plot the data

Comment: @Dimo What MD simulation package is it? There are a number of python-based trajectory readers for many of the major ones.

Comment: I am using a custom extension for hoomd-blue

Comment: If you are really feeling homesick for C: [scanf for Python](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/scanf/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious ways to do it: with or without regexps. Since you're probably going to get 300 regexp answer, let's show how to do it without.

We want to strip the parens, then split on either whitespace or comma followed by whitespace. Another way to say that is: strip the parens, then split on whitespace, then strip the optional trailing commas. For example:

```
line = line[1:-1] # strip the parens
bits = line.split() # split on whitespace
bits = [bit.rstrip(',') for bit in bits] # strip trailing commas
bits = map(float, bits) # convert to float
```

And you can of course merge this all into one line:

```
bits = [float(bit.rstrip(',')) for bit in line[1:-1].split()]
```

Comment: I usually do something like `.strip().strip('()')` rather than `[1:-1]`.  Feels safer somehow..

Comment: @DSM: But you're still processing invalid lines without comment, possibly even _more_ incorrectly, so that feeling is just an illusion. If you want to validate the input, you'll want an explicit check—maybe just `assert line.startswith('(') and line.endswith(')')`.

Comment: I regularly encounter files with inconsistent trailing whitespace -- I wonder sometimes if there's a tutorial somewhere recommending `'\n'.join(stuff)` -- so you're not going to convince me that doing a blind `[1:-1]` is better than explicitly removing bounding whitespace and parentheses.  At least I know what characters I'm removing, and that knowledge -- though I agree it's nonvalidating -- avoids a class of bugs I'd otherwise regularly encounter.  So it's only illusory in the sense that the Tao which can be perceived is not the true Tao.

Comment: @DSM: Stripping off the trailing whitespace is a separate and completely independent issue from stripping off the parens. You can do `line.rstrip()[1:-1]`. And you can do `line.strip('()')`. Meanwhile, what bugs have you ever caught with `strip('()')` that you wouldn't also have caught with `[1:-1]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
txt=['(1.323232, 1.22323, 3.23123)',
      '(1.32.3232, 1.22323, 3.23123)',
      '(1.323232 1.22323 3.23123)']

data=[]  
for i, s in enumerate(txt):
    st=s.strip().lstrip('(').rstrip(')')  
    if ',' in s:
        res=[e.strip() for e in st.split(',')]
    else:
        res=st.split()
    try:    
        res=map(float, res) 
    except ValueError:
        print 'Element {} "{}" is invalid'.format(i,s)    
        continue   

    data.append(res)   

print 'data:', data
```

Prints:

```
Element 1 "(1.32.3232, 1.22323, 3.23123)" is invalid
data: [[1.323232, 1.22323, 3.23123], [1.323232, 1.22323, 3.23123]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write something like the other answers, but, for completeness, I'll be the regex guy

```
import re
f = open('myfile', 'r')
r = re.compile(r'\-*\d+\.*\d+')
data =[]
for line in f:
    data.append(map(float, r.findall(line)))
```

Answer (score 0):

changing the re into

```
r'\-*\d+\.*\d*'
```

will also catch single digit numbers e.g. (1, 2, 3)

```
import re
f = open('myfile', 'r')
r = re.compile(r'\-*\d+\.*\d*')
data =[]
for line in f:
    data.append(map(float, r.findall(line)))
```